# Scrolling event of Listbox

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have called json request & it will give me 20 items at one call.I have set this 20 items in my page but actually total item are 1000, now i want to call another 20 data & load it in same page  after scrolling so which event of scrollviewer i have to handle so that i will manage all items in one page?

ListBox look Like:

```
<ListBox Name="lstSubNews" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="lstSubNews_SelectionChanged" 
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource ListColor}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="5,0.8,5,0.8">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="90" Width="500" Background="AliceBlue" >
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="420"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding subject}"Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding poster}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollViewer which is within the ListBox template and handle the ValueChanged event of listbox which occurs as soon as scrolling starts.

Comment: @ Pradeep Kesharwani IF you are able to give example ?

Comment: @Viraj here i am just giving you a idea to solve your problem you a having a web service which gives you 20 items as response and i am not having such web service, that's way i could not apply it as demo for you

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the `ScrollViewer` and then detect when the user scrolls to the bottom.

```cs
var border = (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(lstSubNews, 0) as Border);
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = border.Child as ScrollViewer;

scrollViewer.ViewChanged += async (a, t) =>
    {
        if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset > scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight - 5)
        {
            //code here
        }
    };
```

However the right way of doing would be to implement the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading